# What is the simplest way to backup a zfs file system to a second drive

Tags: backup, 20.04, zfs

When I upgraded to ubuntu 20.04 I started using zfs in my root file system. Until now I was using the program backuppc. Now that I have zfs root file system what is the best/simplest way to back up to a second drive on the same computer (and what if it is on a different local computer). my root is nvme. If the second drive is a non nvme SSD. Is that an issue.

Comment: I agree with Gordan; sanoid and syncoid are awesome tools for zfs. Sanoid creates snapshots and syncoid replicates to local or remote stores.

Comment: I am also using syncoid. It has  a conflict with zsys. I need to export the backup drive after each daily backup so that zsys will not have any issue.

Comment: I have been using sanoid for some time but am new to using syncoid. Have you posted your syncoid/zsys issue anywhere where you can share the link?

Comment: In my system zsys does not work if the backup drive is imported. I also had a discussion about that with the zsys maintainer.

Answer (score 2):

Dissimilar disks are not an issue.
The easiest way is to use snapshots and `zfs send | receive`.

I can highly recommend sanoid / syncoid for automating this: https://github.com/jimsalterjrs/sanoid/

Answer (score 0):

ZFS autobackup would be the easiest way: It can do both local and remote backups and doest require and extra tools on the backup target. besides zfs :)

https://github.com/psy0rz/zfs_autobackup